# Multiple @POST annotation for same resource class in Jersey?

Tags: jakarta-ee, post, annotations, jersey-1.0

I am not able to find a definite answer to my question. I am trying to create two or more @POST methods within the same resource. The difference is in how the resource is created - the JSON request in the body will be different. Does this go against the RESTful guidelines? Is this possible?

Example, is the following possible?

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Response postMethodOne(MyObjectOne obj) {
    ...
}

@POST
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Response postMethodTwo(MyObjectTwo obj) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looking for the same thing here. Hit me up if you find anything.